# How can I check if two outlets are connected to the same electrical circuit?

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have some internet problems, and I was thinking to buy a [PowerLine](https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5509_TL-WPA7510-KIT.html), that will help me extend the WiFi range. The thing is, to get this PowerLine working, both need to be conected to the same electrical circuit. So, one of my outlets is in A room, near the router, and the other outlet is in the B room. How can I check if the outlets are connected to the same circuit?

I live in an apartment, and I have a circuit breaker. Here is a photo:

[image]

Comment: Same circuit? Are you sure? I used one of these to improve upstairs internet and the other was downstairs - guaranteed they were on different circuits...

Comment: https://www.tp-link.com/us/products/details/cat-5509_TL-WPA7510-KIT.html . On the site is says that they should be conected at the same circuit.

Comment: In this case “same circuit” should be interpreted to mean “same phase”.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To determine if sockets are on the same circuit switch off the circuit breakers one at a time to cut power to one socket and then check if the other one is cut too.

I have no idea what a "PowerLine" is and you haven't provided a link.
If it is a socket strip with a built in filter then it only protects devices plugged into it and not into the other sockets in the building.

---

Update:

It appears that you are asking about a WiFi extender that transmits data over the mains. Your fuseboard is single-phase so all circuits share the same live and neutral. The device should work.

Comment: Is this 100 % ? They are expensive, and I don't want to waste my money on something that won't work. Thanks!

Comment: If you did the tests as suggested and got the expected results then the sockets are on the same circuit. 100%. Will the devices work? I have no idea.

Answer (score 2):

Plug lights into the various sockets around the apartment and turn them on. Switch off the breakers one at a time, and go round checking which lights have gone out. You can label the breakers to make life easier next time.

Answer (score 0):

The device you link to will work - same circuit is loosely written by Marketing probably... Same household supply is probably more accurate.

As I put in my comment I used a pair of these, one downstairs and one up, both on different power circuits fed from the same supply board in the house.

Fit them and test.

Comment: So, you put both on different outlets, on different circuits, and they still worked?

Comment: Yes, exactly as explained in my answer : downstairs power ring, upstairs power ring, **different rooms on different floors**... worked fine doing exactly what they are designed to do. Look at the image provided in the link you gave...